# Virtualbox kernel modules not loading at boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I have been running virtualbox on an Ubuntu 12.04 laptop for a while and it has all worked smooth, but suddenly, probably after a kernel upgrade, the vbox* modules are not loading at boot, if I manually modprobe them, it all works fine, but that should not be needed ...

Looking at the `/etc/init.d/virtualbox`, it seems as I should add `LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE=1` to `/etc/default/virtualbox`, but for other machines it works without that line...

Any clues?

Comment: You using the latest version of virtual box?

Comment: Why don't you just set the option in the config file

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this computer is running an older version of Virtual Box. The environment variable, `LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE` is only needed in an obsolete version of VB: VirtualBox Open Source Edition (i.e. OSE).

That variable was used to control the loading of the VB OSE kernel modules. Setting it to a 0 made them not load, setting it to a 1 made them load... which is your issue.

The fact that the `modprobe` resolves your issue I think proves my point.

#### References

- [Virtualbox on Debian Wiki](http://tweenpath.net/?p=625)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. The strange thing is that it worked fine, and then suddenly died. a few colleagues of mine has the same setup without any problems.

Comment: vboxmanage --version
4.1.12_Ubuntur77245